# How to set current date to a fixed value in hsqldb?

Tags: junit, hsqldb

For my unit tests I need to freeze the current date. Otherwise the unit tests that work today will break next week.

Is there a way to freeze the current date (or sysdate) in HSQLDB?

Comment: What do unit tests have to do with HSQLDB? Show us an example of code that you're testing and of the corresponding test.

Comment: Are you doing date processing in SQL, using functions like 'now()'?

Comment: Here'e the query that gets executed: It finds all project ids between today and two weeks from now. I would like to write unit tests to test this query. But, since sysdate changes each day and fixture data is fixed, unit tests that work today won't work in the future since the dates between sysdate and sysdate+14 have changed.                                                                       `SELECT project_id
FROM project
WHERE (live_date BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate) AND TRUNC(sysdate+14));`